# Dynamically sized stackView for less content

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have *custom XIB's* which I will be using to create my ViewController at runtime. Which all XIB's are to be included inside the ViewController will be decided at runtime.

I am using a `stackView` for that purpose which I have added to the storyboard and constrained it to *leading-triling-top-bottom* of the `superView`. That means the stackView will be stretched to the height of the `viewController`.

Now when i have few Custom Views(or XIB), say 3, it should not cover the complete screen but rather stick to it's size and be added to the stackView

But my problem arises here: Since I have constrained the stackView to complete screen(as sometimes the number of XIB can be a lot more and will surpass the size of the screen and hence I might need a scrollable stackView), it shows like this

[image]

I have found kind of a hack [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/02/20/uistackview-stacking-child-views/) but I don't think that's gonna cut

**StackView's Alignment - Fill, Distribution - Equal Spacing (0)**

Comment: remove the constraint for the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by :

1. Removing the bottom constraint of the stackView
2. Changing the `Intrinsic size` under *Size Inspector* from **System Defined** to **Placeholder** and setting the `height` to *1*

Answer (score 0):

**step 1.** make the bottom constraint between super view and your stack view as `Equal or more`

**step 2.**
make the height constraint to your stack view with priority 1 and constant 0

**step 3.**
ensure you views inside stack view layouts correctly - all edges should be installed in each views